# Adding magento2 extension to composer. Code hosted on Assembla

Tags: git, magento, composer-php, magento2, assembla

I have an extension which is published on magento marketplace. I want to add it to composer to let users install it from there as well.

I tried the following steps

1. Registered with [getcomposer](https://getcomposer.org/)
2. Submitted my Assembla repository at [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/submit)

But it gave the following error

> Uncaught Exception: [RuntimeException] Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://git.assembla.com/myplugin.git' '/home/composer/.composer/cache/vcs/https---git.assembla.com-myplugin.git/' Cloning into bare repository '/home/composer/.composer/cache/vcs/https---git.assembla.com-myplugin.git'... fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.assembla.com/myplugin.git/'

Any help here will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your full error?

Comment: @Ronn0 I have updated the post to reflect full exception.

Comment: As you see there is an authentication error.

Comment: @Ronn0, You are correct. I guess the authentication error is because repositories are private in assembla. So, now I am thinking to create a public repository in github and publish it. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: So, here is what I did. I moved my code from assembla to github and referred to github's repository in composer. That solved all the issues.